# How to create connection with node.js and MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
Code = require('mongodb').Code,
BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
assert = require('assert');

// Set up the connection to the local db
var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017), {native_parser: true});

// Open the connection to the server
mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {

// Get the first db and do an update document on it
var db = mongoclient.db("braj");
db.collection('logintbl').update({a:1}, {b:1}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  assert.equal(1, result);

// Get another db and do an update document on it
  var db2 = mongoclient.db("braj");
  db2.collection('logintbl').update({a:1}, {b:1}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   assert.equal(1, result);

// Close the connection
  mongoclient.close();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So where does it not work? Do you get any error messages? It's easier to help if you are more spesific :)

Comment: At the line that is given below should generate error when i run my code on terminal(ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit) why , i don't know , please suggest me where i am  wrong .... !

Comment: /usr/local/nodejs/bin/MyWork/Live_1/connect.js:10
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
                              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/nodejs/bin/MyWork/Live_1/connect.js:10:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:462:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:480:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:10)
    at startup (node.js:132:16)
    at node.js:817:3